# PowerShell v3 Managing Share/NTFS Permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, share, ntfs

**Background:**

I've been trying to write a PowerShell script to add/remove permissions for a folder. This script is the 5th script in a sequence of scripts that kick off after another. The scripts have shared variables, etc.

**Scripts are as follows:**

1. Create AD Group Object
2. Create AD User Object (or two, three, four,
   etc.)
3. Create User Folder on Application Server and Create Data
   Folder (to be shared by all associated users) on the File Server
4. This script, which will change the permissions to be what they are
   supposed to be

**I'm trying to do the following (NTFS):**

1. User Folder - *SYSTEM (Full), Administrator (Full), Domain Admin (Full), AD Group (Modify), USERS (Modify)*
2. Data Folder - *SYSTEM (Full), Administrator (Full), Domain Admin (Full), AD Group (Modify), NETWORK SERVICE (FULL), USERS (READ)*

**I'm trying to do the following (Share):**

1. Data Folder - *SYSTEM (Full), Administrator (Full), Domain Admin (Full), AD Group (Modify)*

**Here is what I've been trying to work with:**

If I use this method locally, it works great. It shares a folder such as "C:Test" without issue. But I can't get this to run against the servers (not sure if it's because I'm using variables or what). In this case, just the data folder is what I'm trying to change permissions on.

```
# Configures the folders to have necessary permissions

# Set the folder path

# gname, sharedcomputername, and clientname all come from values in previous script

$Server = $ShareComputerName
$Share = "\d$\Tran\"+$ClientName 
$FullSharePath = "$Server"+"$Share"

# Assign the permissions

net share $gname=$FullSharePath '/Grant:Administrators,FULL' '/Grant:Domain\Account,CHANGE'
```

***Server OS is 2008 R2 and PowerShell v3. The DC/AD is 2012 though.***

---

**EDIT 4/2/15 -** This is not a duplicate question (I guess someone marked it as such)...see my response to the user below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing a folder and setting permissions in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399971/sharing-a-folder-and-setting-permissions-in-powershell)

Comment: Hi @SoheilHashemi, while it's similar, the link in the discussion no longer works. Also, the code listed in that link isn't working for me (see above) because I'm (guessing) using variables ($gname=$FullSharePath) instead of mapped drives or whatever. That's why I posted...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**EDIT 4/6/15** - How I accomplished what I was looking to do...

Here is what I ended up doing, thanks to the pointer (to other threads/sources) from Rich Chiavaroli.

**To handle the NTFS Permissions, I did the following:**

```
# Setting NTFS directory permissions

$acl = Get-Acl "\\$servername\folderpath"

$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\user or usergroup","Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Users","Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

Set-Acl "\\$servername\folderpath" $acl
```

**To handle the Share Permissions, I did the following:**

```
# Configures the folders to have necessary permissions

# Set the folder path

$Server = Enter your server name here (ex: \\test)
$Share = Enter the path to the folder here (ex: C:\Test)

# Assign the Share Permissions

# User Name/Group to give permissions to
$trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trustee.Domain = "Corp"
$trustee.Name = "$gname"

$trustee2 = ([wmiclass]'Win32_trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trustee2.Domain = "Domain"
$trustee2.Name = "Domain Admins"

# Access mask values
$fullcontrol = 2032127
$change = 1245631
$read = 1179785

# Create access-list
$ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$ace.AccessMask = $fullcontrol
$ace.AceFlags = 3
$ace.AceType = 0
$ace.Trustee = $trustee

$ace2 = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$ace2.AccessMask = $fullcontrol
$ace2.AceFlags = 3
$ace2.AceType = 0
$ace2.Trustee = $trustee2

# Security descriptor containing access
$sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').psbase.CreateInstance()
$sd.ControlFlags = 4
$sd.DACL = $ace, $ace2
$sd.group = $trustee
$sd.owner = $trustee

$newShare = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -List -ComputerName "$Server"
$newShare.create("$Share", "Name of the share", 0, 100, "", "", $sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using NET SHARE, which is only meant to share a local directory. You can't use it to share a remote directory. You'd have to run NET SHARE on the remote system. There are a couple options though. One would be to use PowerShell Remoting to remote in to the server and then run your NET SHARE command. Another would be to use WMI to remotely create the share.

Using Remoting should be straight forward, but WMI is a little trickier. The issue is permissions. Here are a couple links to look at.

[One approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345972/powershell-invoke-wmimethod-to-create-a-sharefolder-remotely-with-full-control)

[Another approach without permissions.](http://newdelhipowershellusergroup.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-shares-remotely-using.html)

[Docs on the Create method for Win32_Share.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - You could use this in combination with the second link to add in a security descriptor.

Comment: Thank you @Rich Chiavaroli. The information under link "One Approach." worked great for the share. Now I just need to figure out how to edit the NTFS permissions of the folder.